Proving potentially incorrect fact about zeroes regular functions on elliptic curves
Ben Lynn writes

Fact: Every nonconstant regular function has at least two finite zeroes.

where the regular functions are defined as $\mathcal{E}(K) = K[X, Y] / \langle f \rangle$ for the irreducible curve equation $f(X, Y)$. The reasoning for this completely escapes me, so therefore, my understanding of its intention should probably be wrong. In particular, if we take the small example $f(X, Y) = Y^2 - X^3 - X - 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$, which has rational points $(0, 1), (0, -1), (2, 2), (2, -2)$, we can see that the regular function $X \mapsto X^4 + 1$ has no zeroes on $\mathcal{E}$, and is non-constant as it takes the values $1$ and $3$. So, what gives? This is also non-constant with no zeroes in $\mathbb{F}_7^2$ as well.
EDIT: If we assume $k$ is algebraically closed, we can make some progress. In particular, let
$$ \begin{aligned} f(X, Y) &= X^3 + a_2 X^2 + a_4 X + a_6 - Y^2 - a_1 X Y - a_3 Y \\
&= (X^3 + a_2 X^2 + a_4 X + a_6) - (a_1 X + a_3) Y - Y^2 \\
&= (a_6 - Y^2 - a_3 Y) + (a_4 - a_1 Y) X + a_2 X^2 + X^3
\end{aligned} $$
be the elliptic curve equation
Write $g(X, Y) = \bar{g}(X) = g_0(Y) + g_1(Y) X + g_2(Y) X^2 + \cdots + g_d(Y) X^d$. We can compute the resultant with respect to $X$ as
$$ \begin{aligned}
(-1)^{3d} g_d(Y)^3 \prod_{i = 1}^d f(\lambda_i, Y) &= (-1)^{3d} g_d(Y)^3 \prod_{i = 1}^d \left(-Y^2 - (a_1 \lambda_i + a_3) Y + \left(\lambda_i^3 + a_2 \lambda_i^2 + a_4 \lambda_i + \lambda_i\right)\right) \\
&= g_d(Y)^3 \prod_{i = 1}^d \left(Y^2 + (a_1 \lambda_i + a_3) Y - \left(\lambda_i^3 + a_2 \lambda_i^2 + a_4 \lambda_i + \lambda_i\right)\right).
\end{aligned} $$
We can interpret this result (I believe) as follows. Because the resultant has degree $D = 2d + 3\deg_Y g_d$, there are $D$ values of $Y$ such that there exists an $x_0$ such that $X - x_0$ is a factor of both $f, g$ when viewed as a polynomial in $X$ at that particular $Y$. If we call the $Y$ values $y_1, \dots, y_D$ and correspondingly the $X$ values as $x_1, \dots, x_D$, $f(x_i, y_i) = g(x_i, y_i) = 0$.
However, we can compute the other resultant in $Y$.
Write $g(X, Y) = \bar{g}'(Y) = g'_0(X) + g'_1(X) Y + g'_2(X) Y^2 + \cdots + g'_e(X) Y^e$. Again, compute the resultant, but this time in $Y$, as
$$ \begin{aligned}
(-1)^{2e} g'_e(X)^2 \prod_{i = 1}^e f(X, \mu_i) &= g'_e(X)^2 \prod_{i = 1}^e \left(X^3 + a_2 X^2 + (a_4 - a_1 \mu_i) X + \left(a_6 - a_3 \mu_i - \mu_i^2\right)\right).
\end{aligned} $$
This has degree $D' = 3e + 2 \deg_X g'_e$, which gets us $(x'_1, y'_1), \dots, (x'_{D'}, y'_{D'})$ values where $f(x'_i, y'_i) = g(x'_i, y'_i) = 0$.
For the former case, if the $g_i$ are not dependent on $Y$, and in particular $g_d$, then $d \geq 1$ implies the result because $g$ is  non-constant. For the latter case, if we treat it as a constant polynomial in $Y$, or $e = 0$, the degree of the linear term in $X$ must also be at least $1$, also implying the result. However, I think it makes sense that we want $D = D'$, as resultant $= 0 \iff$ they share a common root, but no amount of squinting has given me a clear path forward asides from the obvious case where the maximal power of $X$ and $Y$ appear in the same term of the polynomial expansion of $g$, thereby forcing $d = \deg_X g'_e$ and $e = \deg_y g_d$.
EDIT2: Doing some more experimentation, it is not hard to come up with two polynomials $f(X, Y)$ and $g(X, Y)$ such that $\deg_X \operatorname{res}_Y(f, g) \neq \deg_Y \operatorname{res}_X(f, g)$, so somehow we can end up with a differing number of zeroes depending on the resultant we go through. That seems very strange and I am very interested in what I am missing.

In all likelihood (although the author seems sloppy about this), the claim is about an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field.

I hate it when I prove incorrect facts. =)

@Aphelli When we expand the curve to have points in the closure, it does indeed make a bit more sense. The resultant $\operatorname{Res}_X (g, f)$ with $\operatorname{deg} g \geq 1$ does produce a minimum degree $2$ polynomial in $Y$.
